# Activity has a leaked IntentReceiver( NOT DUPLICATE )

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an activity where I load a URL in a WebView. But on closing that activity I am getting an error

```
Activity com.myOrg.packageName.app.activity.CustomUrlActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopBrowserAccessibilityManager$1@65d420b that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                       android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.com.myOrg.packageName.app.activity.CustomUrlActivity has leaked IntentReceiver org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopBrowserAccessibilityManager$1@65d420b that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:918)
                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:719)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1172)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1152)
                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1146)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:554)
                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:554)
                                                                           at org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopBrowserAccessibilityManager.<init>(LollipopBrowserAccessibilityManager.java:3)
                                                                           at org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.BrowserAccessibilityManager.create(BrowserAccessibilityManager.java:2)
                                                                           at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
                                                                           at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:7)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have not made any call to register any receiver. Please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You have to unregister all receivers used in the activity in onDestroy() method.

Comment: looks like interal problem of WebView implementation ... [someone has similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744881/activity-has-leaked-intentreceiver-lollipopbrowseraccessibilitymanager) ... if it is not crashing application I would not bother about it in you shoes(eventually fill the bug reportin chromium project)

Comment: Are you sure that this is an error, not a warning, and it hurts you?

Comment: @VladMatvienko - It does not produce a crash but shows as an error log.

Comment: @UmeshLohani, really? after 4 month?
If you don't register any receivers by yourself, then it is just a bug in your device's firmware, and you can do nothing about it. But if you do register, then you should unregister them for sure.

Comment: My answer to a 'duplicate' of this question may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596543/1683141