# Activity has leaked IntentReceiver org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopWebContentsAccessibility

Tags: android

I  currently face this error:

> Activity me.akaruikage.bkntools.VTPHeute has leaked IntentReceiver org.chromium.content.browser.accessibility.LollipopWebContentsAccessibility$1@5653daf that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

With this Activity code:

```
package me.akaruikage.bkntools;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class VTPHeute extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vtpheute);
    setWebViewSize();
    initWebView();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    // TODO: Implement this method
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

void setWebViewSize() {
    WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.vtp_heute_webview);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) outMetrics.widthPixels * 2;
    v.setLayoutParams(params);
}

void initWebView() {
    WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.vtp_heute_webview);
    v.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    v.loadUrl("https://mese.webuntis.com/WebUntis/monitor?school=BK-Niederberg&monitorType=subst&format=Vertretungen");
}
}
```

I've looked up here at StackOverflow and couldn't find a suitable solution to this. Looking at the Webview it only shows the default android error page with `"net::ERR_CACHE_MISS"`

I have another App with the exact same code and over there it works flawlessly.

EDIT: I fixed it by taking the code and placed it into a new app.

Comment: If you have found a solution please share.

Comment: I have this same problem in one of my Apps, I'm hoping to find an answer here for this as I have seen nothing elsewhere.

Comment: Please see my answer to a 'duplicate' of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596543/1683141